# Matlab guide starts with axes already plotted

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I created an application using GUIDE called (main). Inside the form (figure), i dragged and dropped many components, one of them is an axes component. When i run the application, it shows allways the same plot. GUIDE generated applications have an opening function, in my case, main_OpeningFcn. I already tried to clear (cla) it in the first line of main_OpeningFcn function, but it first blinks and old plot and then clears it. I am sure it is an old plot, i can recognize it. It seems like this old plot had been saved somewhere and everytime the application starts, it is shown. Is there any cache or something like that?

Comment: We would like to help but your question is too vague. As an experienced user on StackOverflow, I am sure you can describe this problem better. An old plot must be initiated somewhere in your code. You can locate it by looking for some plot initiative functions such as `figure`, `axes`. A hint to that axes such as text in label would help, too.

Comment: Do you call the functions `cla` or `gca` anywhere in your code? If no axis exists, these will create one when called.

Comment: Recommend reviewing this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on asking questions. Then [edit] question accordingly and you'll get much more useful help.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Sorry about the poor description. I edited to try to explain a litle bit beter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you accidently clicked on the save icon in your figure from the gui-window (not guide-window). Now when you open your gui, matlab will not create an empty plot, but will load whatever is saved in the fig-file, that exists beside the m-file for your guide-application.

To solve the issue, you need to delete the figure in your guide-editor, an place a new figure instead. And try to hide the menubar to avoid clicking the save icon again, if your gui is open.